# Wireshark lua api: create new heuristic dissectors table

Tags: lua, wireshark

I found very useful example of heuristic tables usage in Lua.
[a link](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=dissector.lua)
But it doesn't not cover my case.

I've written custom dissector in lua. Described custom protocol has many subprotos. So I create new subdissectors table DissectorTable.new() and register new subprotos.
But some of subprotocols doesn't have identification sign and their types must be found out dynamically.

I hoped to register heuristic dissector with proto:register_heuristic() method, but there is no my new table in DissectorTable.heuristic_list() list.

Creating new dissector table does not create heuristic dissectors table.
Is there a way to create new own heuristic dissectors table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to create a real heuristic dissector table for your protocol in the current Lua API, but I'm not sure it makes a lot of sense to have such a thing.  The purpose of having a protocol create a heuristic dissector table for itself is so that other protocols can register their heuristic dissectors into it - for example the UDP protocol creates a heuristic dissector table named "udp", so that other protocols like RTP, STUN, Skype, etc., can all register their heuristic dissectors into it, and UDP can try them all without knowing about them before-hand.

But when you create a new protocol in a Lua plugin, no other code is going to know about your new protocol or any heuristic dissector table you create.  Only your own Lua code will know about it.  Obviously your new protocol might have subprotocols that need to be tried heuristically, as you appear to need, but you don't need a heuristic dissector table to do that - just call your subprotocols's heuristic dissector functions directly in Lua.

For example:

```
local myProto     = Proto("myproto",     "My Main Protocol")
local mySubproto1 = Proto("mysubproto1", "My First Sub-Protocol")
local mySubproto2 = Proto("mysubproto2", "My Second Sub-Protocol")

-- the sub-prpotocol's heuristic function
-- returns true if the packet is its protocol and it dissected it
-- otherwise returns false
function heur_dissect_mySubproto1(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- see if the passed in tvb is Subproto1 protocol
    -- and if so then add tree items and such or
    -- call mySubproto1's normal dissector function to do that stuff
    return is_Subproto1
end

function heur_dissect_mySubproto2(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- see if the passed in tvb is Subproto2 protocol
    return is_Subproto2
end

function myProto.dissector(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- do stuff for my main protocol

    -- create a new sub-tvb of what has not been processed by the main protocol
    local newTvb = tvbuf(bytes_parsed_by_myproto):tvb()

    -- call the heuristic dissector functions of my sub protocols
    -- with the portion of the tvb that belongs to them
    if heur_dissect_mySubproto1(newTvb, pktinfo, root) then
        -- do here anything you need to afterwards
    elseif heur_dissect_mySubproto2(newTvb, pktinfo, root) then
        -- do here anything you need to afterwards
    end
end
```

or if you want to be fancier, use a table of your own...

```
local myProto     = Proto("myproto",     "My Main Protocol")
local mySubproto1 = Proto("mysubproto1", "My First Sub-Protocol")
local mySubproto2 = Proto("mysubproto2", "My Second Sub-Protocol")

-- a heuristic dissector table for myProto
local myProto_heuristic_table = {}

-- a function to register into myProto's heuristic table
local function register_heuristic(func)
    myProto_heuristic_table[#myProto_heuristic_table + 1] = func
end

function heur_dissect_mySubproto1(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- do stuff
    return is_Subproto1
end

-- "register" the above function
register_heuristic(heur_dissect_mySubproto1)

function heur_dissect_mySubproto2(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- do stuff
    return is_Subproto2
end

register_heuristic(heur_dissect_mySubproto2)

function myProto.dissector(tvbuf, pktinfo, root)
    -- do stuff for my main protocol

    local newTvb = tvbuf(bytes_parsed_by_myproto):tvb()

    -- call the heuristic dissector functions of my sub protocols
    -- with the portion of the tvb that belongs to them
    for _, func in ipairs(myProto_heuristic_table) do
        -- call the heuristic
        if func(newTvb, pktinfo, root) then
            -- do here anything you need to afterwards
            return
        end
    end
end
```